# Ajax login and get data as json (OpenAM)

Tags: ajax, json, authentication, openam

I want to login as different user once I click on different button via OpenAM and show the result spontaneously. I try to the OpenAM dev guide but got no idea.

http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/dev-guide/#chap-rest
**3.3.1. Authentication & Logout**
(this is wt openam said)

> ## The simplest user name/password authentication returns a tokenId
>   that applications can present as a cookie value for other operations
>   that require authentication. In this case use HTTP POST to prevent the
>   web container from logging the credentials. Pass the user name in an
>   X-OpenAM-Username header, and the password in an X-OpenAM-Password
>   header.
>
> ```
> [-]
> $ curl \
>  --request POST \
>  --header "X-OpenAM-Username: demo" \
>  --header "X-OpenAM-Password: changeit" \
>  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
>  --data "{}" \
>  https://openam.example.com:8443/openam/json/authenticate
> { "tokenId": "AQIC5w...NTcy*", "successUrl": "/openam/console" }
> ```
>
> This "zero page login" mechanism works only for name/password authentication. If you include a POST body with the request, it must
>   be an empty JSON string as shown in the example. Alternatively, you
>   can leave the POST body empty. Otherwise, OpenAM interprets the body
>   as a continuation of an existing authentication attempt, one that uses
>   a supported callback mechanism.
>
> The authentication service at /json/authenticate supports callback
>   mechanisms that make it possible to perform other types of
>   authentication in addition to simple user name/password login.
>
> Callbacks that are not completed based on the content of the client
>   HTTP request are returned in JSON as a response to the request. Each
>   callback has an array of output suitable for displaying to the end
>   user, and input which is what the client must complete and send back
>   to OpenAM. The default is still user name/password authentication.

---

My code main.html

```
$('#try').click(function(){
    var uid="user";
    var password="password";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://mytomcatlocalhost/itapp/app3/app3.jsp",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {"X-OpenAM-Username":uid,"X-OpenAM-Password":password},
        contentType:"application/json",

        success: function(Jdata) {
            alert("h");
        }}

<button id="try">user 1</button>
```

but I am not really sure what is the callback do for, and whether my direction is correct or not.   app3.jsp is an application that only allow user to see after he/she login to openAM successfully. But I got stuck in how to login automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the value for url

```
"https://mytomcatlocalhost/itapp/app3/app3.jsp"
```

is your app URL and not OpenAM REST auth URL ... are you using OpenAM REST in a bean within your jsp?

If not, the code you provided does not really make sense.